# Загрузка *.txt файлов с сайта

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть текстовой файл, в нем содержатся ссылки на текстовые файлы вида:

```
> https://testsite.com/pwned/1542435.txt
> https://testsite.com/pwned/1523435.txt
> https://testsite.com/pwned/2545287.txt
> https://testsite.com/pwned/1596755.txt
> https://testsite.com/pwned/1421341.txt
```

Их очень много. Понимаю бы, если бы они были расположены у меня на хосте, но они находятся на другом сервере и физического доступа даже к ftp я не имею.

Конечно можно было бы воспользоваться простым "save as", но я уже сказал, ссылок очень много. Порядка 3 тысяч. Есть ли способ автоматизировать этот процесс? Пользовался winHTTrack, wget и прочими, но первый никак не может родить, лишь аборты, другой просит сертификат. Флаг -no-certificate не помогает.

Comment: php взрываете свой спиок explode(PHO_EOL, $txt) и дальше циклом  `CURL`; Но на трех тысячах может таймаут случится, так что нужна некая пагинация

Comment: Сложно реализуемо для меня. Можно поподробней описать вашу мысль?

Answer (score 2):

```
$linkstxt = file_get_contents('links.txt');

$links = explode(PHP_EOL, $linkstxt);

foreach ($links as $link){
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $filename = end(explode('/', $link))
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, $data);
}
```

Можно попробовать так запустить, если хватит скорости то должен всё скачать.